# Where should I add my internal classes file in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0

I'm porting an old project to symfony2 in order to start learning the framework and I cannot realize how to properly add some helper functions I have in a PHP file.

Comment: This may help http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). Wrap those function in a class (like `Helper`), define the class as a service and then inject it where needed (controller or another service, or even into a cli command).

The namespace (thus the path, as you tagged the question with psr-0) is up to you.

Comment: I just figured out. My functions actually were a class. I just did´nt have a clue about the namespaces/directory structure with symfony. Your bundle root is the Namespace root! Thanks @Gremo